# Merging Fields into new field using python and eliminating space in before and after the field using field calculator

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser

Am interested in combining ClASS1 and SUBCLASS1 to form the one combined class.  I wrote the expression as follows "() ()" format( !CLASS1!replace(" "","" ),( !SUBCLASS1!replace(" "","" ))as shown in the Image[![field to be combined and expression] [![enter image description here] [image]

but after executing I get the following error message
[image: error message]

Comment: Please always present errors as text rather than pictures.

Answer (score 2):

If spaces before or after the values in `CLASS1` and `SUBCLASS1` are the only issue, the expression could be simplified by using the `strip` method instead:

```
"{} {}".format(!CLASS1!.strip(), !SUBCLASS1!.strip())
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error states, your syntax is wrong. I assume you want to replace spaces with commas. Try this line for your expression:

```
"{} {}".format(!CLASS1!.replace(" ",","),(!SUBCLASS1!.replace(" ",","))
```

**EDIT**:

Since I now see what your data looks like, I guess the `.strip()` option is the nicer choice. If you still want to use the `.replace()` function try this:

```
"{} {}".format(!CLASS1!.replace(" ",""),(!SUBCLASS1!.replace(" ",""))
```

Comment: Should 0 and 1 be in between the curly brackets? like this: "{0}{1}"...  will still work if the curly brackets are empty?

Comment: the {0} and {1} are only necessary, if you refer to the place markes in a different order. example: "{0} {1} {0}".format("A", "B") will return "A B A". so in this case they are not necessary.

Comment: @DelonixR. if no indices are used in the expression, `format` will use the parameters in the order they are entered.